# Enable GPS programmatically in android 4.1 or heigher version

Tags: android, gps

I want to Enable GPS programmatically on android version 4.1 or heigher version. But it is restricted to enable GPS on above 4.0 version. Is there any way to enable it..?? If there is any way so please help me...

Comment: you can not enable gps programetically..

Comment: you can only ask the user to turn on GPS. There is no way for you to switch it on without interaction from the user

Comment: Guide to user to GPS settings Activity, don't take user's decisions yourself.

Comment: okkk but I am making app for tracking mobile after lost. If any one changes sim so I want latitude and longitude of that place. We can do it, but above 4.0 version, how to do it..?? or please tell me other solution to implement it...Thank you

Comment: This is for you [Location Strategies](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can check this code .It is working for me..

```
import android.net.Uri;
import android.provider.Settings

    private void turnGPSOn()
        {
            String provider = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);

            if(!provider.contains("gps"))
            { 
                final Intent poke = new Intent();
                poke.setClassName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.widget.SettingsAppWidgetProvider"); 
                poke.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_ALTERNATIVE);
                poke.setData(Uri.parse("3")); 
                sendBroadcast(poke);
            }
        }
```